# How to implement conditional AutomaticChallenge in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, unauthorized, challenge-response, asp.net-core-middleware

How do I redirect requests coming to some path (web site) to login page but respond with unauthorized to requests coming to another path (API paths)?
As I understand AutomaticChallenge changes this behavior for all the web app. But how to make it conditional?

I use OpenIddict which is OpenId Connect Server configuration library.
And, in general, clients are mobile apps. However it would be nice to have a web site like behavior for some controllers that return views.

Startup code looks this way:

```
        // Add a middleware used to validate access
        // tokens and protect the API endpoints.
        app.UseOAuthValidation();

        app.UseCsp(options => options.DefaultSources(directive => directive.Self())
            .ImageSources(directive => directive.Self()
                .CustomSources("*"))
            .ScriptSources(directive => directive.Self()
                .UnsafeInline())
            .StyleSources(directive => directive.Self()
                .UnsafeInline()));

        app.UseXContentTypeOptions();

        app.UseXfo(options => options.Deny());

        app.UseXXssProtection(options => options.EnabledWithBlockMode());

        app.UseIdentity();

        // Add external authentication middleware below. To configure them please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=532715
        app.UseTwitterAuthentication(...);

        app.UseFacebookAuthentication(...);

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(...);

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseOpenIddict();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSwagger();
        app.UseSwaggerUi();
```

Answer (score 2):

To change `AutomaticChallenge` you can use `MapWhen` or [UseWhen](https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Samples/blob/cdc53b2a132b73bc10fd4dcbb91b169634a589a1/samples/Mvc/Mvc.Server/Extensions/AppBuilderExtensions.cs):

```
// ...
app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
{
      builder.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
      {
            AutomaticChallenge = false,
      });
      // ...
});
app.MapWhen(ctx => !ctx.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
{
      builder.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
      {
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
      });
      // ...
});
```

**But** I think your requirement is not about `AutomaticChallenge`. If request is ajax then `CookieAuthentication` middleware respond with 401 otherwise redirect to login path. So you don't need to conditional middleware.

Comment: You can also use `AuthenticationScheme` for your scenerio. But i can't write an answer for your scenerio because it is to broad for me and there may be many solution.